# How to work with environment variables on Windows/Linux..?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I am trying to work with an OpenAI library (https://github.com/orhanerday/open-ai) that uses environment variables for key storage, but it doesn't seem to be finding the key when I run it.

On my local Windows machine I ran the following command:  `setx OPENAI_API_KEY “mykey”`

On the Linux web server I ran the following command:  `export OPENAI_API_KEY=mykey`

Now on the server when I run the following, I see the correct key value printed back to me:  `printenv OPENAI_API_KEY`

In my script I'm using `$open_ai_key = getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY');` but I'm getting no value back..??

Any information on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you test on Laravel?

Comment: No I'm just using basic PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using orhanerday/OpenAI PHP SDK,

Let's try to set your ‘OPENAI_API_KEY’ Environment Variable through the Control Panel

1. Open System properties and select Advanced system settings
   [image]
2. Select Environment Variables...
   [image]
3. Select New… from the User variables section(top). Add your name/key-value pair, replacing  with your API key.

```
Variable name: OPENAI_API_KEY
Variable value: <yourkey>
```

4. Sign out and then log in to your PC.

[image]

5. Create a PHP file;

```php
<?php
    $open_ai_key = getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY");
    print("OPENAI_API_KEY is; $open_ai_key");
```

6. run the PHP file

```bash
$ php index.php 
> OPENAI_API_KEY is: sk-gjtv.....
```

After running the app you should get the value.